# How would I strip any harmful characters from this form?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have tried both real escape string and other php methods but I am not sure I am using them correctly. This code shows my input and then the ajax post, where and how would I preform the sanitation?

Please note there is no data base connection so all the character stripping would have to be done in jQuery somehow.

Would this be more of the correct direction to go in?

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$message = $_POST["message"];


$msg = "
Name:$name
Email:$email
Phone:$phone
Comment:
$message";


function checkInput($msg) {
    $msg = @strip_tags($msg);
    $msg = @stripslashes($msg);
    $invalid_characters = array("$", "%", "#", "<", ">", "|");
    $msg = str_replace($invalid_characters, "", $msg);
    return $msg;
}


$to = "email address";
$subject = "name";
$message = $msg;
$headers = "Contact form enquiry";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php) inside mail.php

Comment: this isnt going to a database its just creating an email and sending it

Comment: That question covers filtering user input, database inserts are only part of the answer.

Comment: I have tried a similar thing and the emails come through blank

Comment: sorry i misread your question im going to use filter_var rather than trying to do it with jqeury

Answer (score 0):

You perform sanitation *immediately before* you put the text into some code or specific data format.

So in the code you have here:

```
  var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&message=' + message;
```

You would escape each variable before you put it into the URL. You can do that with `encodeURIComponent`. However, you are using jQuery ajax so you shouldn't be doing that by hand in the first place.

```
data: { 'name': name, 'email': email, 'phone': phone, 'message': message},
```

And in the HTML you are generating:

```
   .append("<h2 class='text-center form_submit_text'>Hi " + name + ", we will contact you soon </p>")
```

should be:

```
   var heading = jQuery("<h2>").addClass('text-center').addClass('form_submit_text').text("Hi " + name + ", we will contact you soon);
   $('#thanks').empty().append(heading);
```

You might also need to do some escaping in your PHP, such as [before putting data into SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: So if i just change the code to the above is it going to break my append form?

Answer (score 0):

You validate and sanitize in bin/mail.php. See [filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var) for the built in ways to validate and sanitize incoming data. For example, for email you can do

```
if (filter_var($_POST['email']), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
}
```

Phone numbers would required a regular expression to validate and sanitize (so it only contains numbers and/or re-formats to your preferred format). Free text like `$message` should  use FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING.